# setting working directory in python shell to import a text file

Tags: python, directory, set

I want to import a text file from my desktop to python but I get an error.
Can anyone help explain how can I import the text file from the desktop working directory?

Comment: Can you show us what code you have tried so far? What is in your text file?

Answer (score 0):

Your python program and the text file need to be in she same directory. There is a several ways to open a file in python. If you just want to read it you can do it like this:

```
file = open("File_Name.txt" , "r")
print(file.read())
```

If you want to change your working directory then type:

```
import os
os.chdir(path)
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to change the working directory. Can you please help me?

Comment: You either create a new file, write your code and then save that python file in the same directory as your text file.

Comment: I will edit my answer with code that shows how to change working directory

Comment: instead of setting the path for the whole program it's better to fetch path. even for multiple files to be read `os.path.join()` can be used to fetch the file

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(r"/<path-to-desktop-from-root-directory>/desktop/samp.txt", 'r') as f:  # using raw string to path
    print(f.read())

with open("/<path-to-desktop>/samp.txt", 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

You can also use path directly in windows by using raw string `i.e. r"C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\file.txt"` or using two backslashes `i.e. "C:\\Users\\<username>\\Desktop\\file.txt"` `\` (because backslash is considered as escape character)

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.chdir to change to a directory.  But you don't have to do that.  The best way to get the path to your desktop is with expanduser and then os.path.join to build your file path

```
import os
home = os.path.expanduser('~')
file_path = os.path.join(home, 'Desktop', 'FileName.txt')
with open(file_path, 'rb') as fo:
    data = fo.read()
```